# How to make Yeoman work

Tags: yeoman

I have got Yeoman installed and when I run the `yo` command I get this:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/Richard_Home/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
You don't have access to this file.

at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:56:8)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:19:11)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js:23:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:23:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

[03:35:36] ~ $

I have tried adding this to my `$path:`

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin/npm:$PATH
```

as that is where npm is.

When I do sudo yo install generator-webapp

I get this response:

```
A quick solution would be to change where npm stores global packages by
putting ~/npm/bin in your PATH and running:
npm config set prefix ~/npm
```

I have run `npm config set prefix ~/npm`

I still get the same error access denied.

I just want to run `yo` I have it installed on an iMac and it worked straight away. I am on a macBook.

Comment: Are you able to run `yo doctor`.

Comment: No I can not run yo doctor I get the same error message.